# Table width -different in different browsers when sending via Gmail

Tags: css, browser, html-table, width

I have following table:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" 
                style="position: relative; font-size: 9px;">
                        some text<br>
                        some text<br>
                        some text<br>
                        some text<br>
                </td> 
                <td colspan="2" 
                style="position: relative; padding-left:3%;font-size: 9px;">
                        another text <br>
                        another text<br>
                        another text<br>
                        another text<br>
                       
                   
                </td>
                <td colspan="4" style="padding-left:3%;">
                    <img  src="logo.jpg">
                </td>
    </tr>
        </table>
```

In Mozilla, this table has width:600px, but in Google Chrome, it has width: 700px. My code is the same. If I make `<table width=100%>` in Mozilla, it looks good, but in Chrome, it should be `<table width=80%>`.

How could I make my table compatible with different browsers? I also tried with Bootstrap Grid System, but t's still the same. Problem is different width of div or table.

Edited: This happens when when I send this table as html file via Gmail. When I see it as a view in different browsers, it's good. But when I send it in Gmail, there are differences of table width.

Comment: Something weird is going on with paddings in percents. When using units such as ems or px, everything's fine.

Comment: I have first used in px, but changed it to % and it's still the same. I forgot to write that this happens when I send this table as html file via gmail. When I see it now as view in Mozilla and Chrome, it's the same. It's issue of Gmail, I think.